# es posible en html5 arrastrar imagenes de distintos carrusels a un contenedor?

Tags: html5, funciones, carrusel, drag-and-drop, contenedores

Tengo 4 carruseles de imagenes y un contenedor central. Es una figura a la que le lanzo pelos, ropa superior, pantalones y calzado. Quiero que el contenedor central pueda recibir imagenes de todos los carruseles. Las he hecho del mismo tamaño en png para que se superpongan bien. Pero necesito que si le llega una  imagen de un carrusel y ya tiene colocada otra imagen de este mismo carrusel expulse la vieja para recibir la nueva.

Aquí va el código. No se en que lugar tengo que añadir esta informacion.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Mover Imágenes Arrastrando y Carrusel</title>
  <style>
      .draggable-img {
      cursor: move;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .static-img {
      width: 400px;
      height: 510px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .carousel-container {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .drop-container {
      position: fixed;
      top: 14.5%;
      left: 43.5%;
      width: 200px;
      height: 550px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      z-index: 1;
      background-color: transparent; /* Cambia el color de fondo según tus necesidades */
    }

    .carousel-img {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      object-fit: cover;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 48%;
      right: 45px;
    }

    button {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      background-color: transparent;
      color: black;
      border: none;
      padding: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    #pelo {
      width: 200px;
      height: 550px;
      right: 4%;
      top: 40%
    }

    #falda {
      width: 200px;
      height: 550px;
      right: 4%;
      top: 20%
    }

    #top {
      width: 200px;
      height: 550px;
      right: 4%;
      top: 30%
    }

    #prevBtn {
      right: 0;
      margin-right: 250px;
    }

    #nextBtn {
      right: 0;
      margin-right: 50px;
    }

  .carousel-container-left {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 200vh;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        z-index: 1;
      }

  .carousel-img-left {
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px;
        object-fit: cover;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 48%;
        left: 45px;
      }

  #top-left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 550px;
    top: 30%;
    left: 4%
      }

  #falda-left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 550px;
    top: 20%;
    left: 4%
      }

  #pelo-left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 550px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 4%
      }

  #prevBtn-left {
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 250px
      }

  #nextBtn-left {
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 50px
}

.carousel-img,
.carousel-img-left {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      object-fit: cover;
      z-index: 2;
      position: absolute;
    }

.carousel-img {
      top: 48%;
      right: 45px;
    }

.carousel-img-left {
      top: 48%;
      left: 45px;
    }

.draggable-img {
      cursor: move;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Contenedor estático del maniquí -->
  <img class="static-img" src="maniquiEDITAT.png" alt="imagen estática">

  <!-- Carrusel derecho -->
  <div id="carousel-container">
    <img class="draggable-img carousel-img" id="falda" src="faldilla.png" alt="falda" onmousedown="startDragging(event, this)">
    <img class="draggable-img carousel-img" id="top" src="top.png" alt="top" onmousedown="startDragging(event, this)">
    <img class="draggable-img carousel-img" id="pelo" src="cabell.png" alt="pelo" onmousedown="startDragging(event, this)">

    <button id="prevBtn" onclick="prevImage('carousel-container', 'carousel-img')">←</button>
    <button id="nextBtn" onclick="nextImage('carousel-container', 'carousel-img')">→</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Carrusel izquierdo -->
  <div id="carousel-container-left">
    <img class="draggable-img carousel-img-left" id="falda-left" src="faldilla.png" alt="falda-left" onmousedown="startDragging(event, this)">
    <img class="draggable-img carousel-img-left" id="top-left" src="top.png" alt="top-left" onmousedown="startDragging(event, this)">
    <img class="draggable-img carousel-img-left" id="pelo-left" src="cabell.png" alt="pelo-left" onmousedown="startDragging(event, this)">

    <button id="prevBtn-left" onclick="prevImage('carousel-container-left', 'carousel-img-left')">→</button>
    <button id="nextBtn-left" onclick="nextImage('carousel-container-left', 'carousel-img-left')">←</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Contenedor de destino para las imágenes arrastrables -->
  <div class="drop-container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <!-- Puedes agregar estilos específicos para el contenedor de destino aquí -->
  </div>

  <script>
    let currentIndex = 0;
    let currentIndexLeft = 0;

    function showImage(container, imgClass, index) {
      const images = document.querySelectorAll(`#${container} .${imgClass}`);

      images.forEach((img, i) => {
        img.style.display = i === index ? 'block' : 'none';
      });
    }

    function prevImage(container, imgClass) {
      if (container === 'carousel-container') {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + 3) % 3;
        showImage(container, imgClass, currentIndex);
      } else if (container === 'carousel-container-left') {
        currentIndexLeft = (currentIndexLeft - 1 + 3) % 3;
        showImage(container, imgClass, currentIndexLeft);
      }
    }

    function nextImage(container, imgClass) {
      if (container === 'carousel-container') {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % 3;
        showImage(container, imgClass, currentIndex);
      } else if (container === 'carousel-container-left') {
        currentIndexLeft = (currentIndexLeft + 1) % 3;
        showImage(container, imgClass, currentIndexLeft);
      }
    }

    // ...

  function startDragging(e, element) {
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var xOffset = e.clientX - rect.left;
    var yOffset = e.clientY - rect.top;

    // Crear una copia de la imagen original con todos los estilos
    var clone = element.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "clone"; // Asegurarse de que tenga un ID único
    clone.style.position = "absolute";
    clone.style.zIndex = "3";

    // Obtener los estilos de la imagen original
    var computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(element);

    // Aplicar los estilos al clon
    Array.from(computedStyles).forEach(style => {
      clone.style[style] = computedStyles[style];
    });

    document.body.appendChild(clone);

    function dragMove(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var x = e.clientX - xOffset;
      var y = e.clientY - yOffset;
      setTranslate(x, y, clone);
    }

    function dragEnd() {
      // Cambiar el contenedor de destino al soltar la imagen
      const dropContainer = document.querySelector('.drop-container');
      dropContainer.appendChild(clone);

      // Ajustar la posición al soltar la imagen dentro del nuevo contenedor
      clone.style.left = "0";
      clone.style.top = "0";

      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", dragMove);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd);
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd);
  }

  // ...

    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, element) {
      element.style.left = xPos + "px";
      element.style.top = yPos + "px";
    }

    function allowDrop(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    function drop(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      const draggedElement = document.getElementById(data);
      e.target.appendChild(draggedElement);
    }

    // Mostrar la primera imagen al cargar la página
    showImage('carousel-container', 'carousel-img', currentIndex);
    showImage('carousel-container-left', 'carousel-img-left', currentIndexLeft);

    // Function to handle click on an image in drop-container
    function returnToCarousel(imgId, containerId, imgClass) {
      const dropContainer = document.querySelector('.drop-container');
      const carouselContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);

      // Create a new image element and set its attributes
      const newImage = document.createElement('img');
      newImage.src = document.getElementById(imgId).src;
      newImage.alt = document.getElementById(imgId).alt;
      newImage.id = imgId;
      newImage.classList.add('draggable-img', imgClass);

      // Remove the existing image from drop-container
      dropContainer.removeChild(document.getElementById(imgId));

      // Append the new image to the carousel at its initial position
      carouselContainer.appendChild(newImage);

      // Add the event listener for dragging to the new image
      newImage.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        startDragging(e, newImage);
      });
    }

    // ...

    // Event listener to handle click on an image in drop-container
    document.querySelector('.drop-container').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('draggable-img')) {
        // Get the id of the clicked image
        const clickedImgId = e.target.id;

        // Determine the container and image class based on the clicked image id
        let container, imgClass;
        if (clickedImgId.endsWith('-left')) {
          container = 'carousel-container-left';
          imgClass = 'carousel-img-left';
        } else {
          container = 'carousel-container';
          imgClass = 'carousel-img';
        }

        // Call the function to return the image to its initial position
        returnToCarousel(clickedImgId, container, imgClass);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si, es posible.

Comment: Que funcion tendría que añadir? No soy muy experta en programacion.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: Ahí tienes un ejemplo, fíjate que tienes siempre al menos 2 elementos, el objeto draggable (todas tus imágenes) y el elemento donde se "dropea"

Comment: OK gracias. Lo que no se hacer es eliminar una imagen del contenedor cuando lanzo otra del mismo carrusel para que no me queden dos cabezas o dos camisetas superpuestas.

Comment: Es que eso ya depende de tu implementación, difícilmente alguien podrá brindar una respuesta con la información que has mostrado en tu pregunta.  Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [MCVE] (con énfasis en lo mínimo!!!), donde muestres el HTML y el JS

Comment: Antes de `dropContainer.appendChild(clone);` coloca `dropContainer.innerHTML=""`